# Why are users prompted "Account recovery requires verified contact information" on every login in my Amplify app?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I created an amplify backend using the CLI. I used the manual process to set up the authorization `amplify add auth` and everything is working except that every time a user logs in they are prompted to verify their e-mail by the Amplify SignUp component

In the Cognito console I can see that their e-mail has been verified and the process of sending the code and entering it works as expected. But if the user signs out and signs back in they receive the prompt again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer in the thread of this github issue: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2730#issuecomment-468005207

During the configuration when I chose the read attributes I did not select the "Email Verified?" attribute. Since it couldn't be read it came back falsey and so amplifies SignUp component prompts the user to verify every time.